# Jenkins multiple dependency does not work properly (Trigger,PrerequisitiesCheck)

Tags: jenkins

*Background of the problem*

We are using jenkins to build lots of projects that are dependent to some of the projects. 
As most of you know, jenkins allows you to trigger another job if the build is stable (stability is an option that we want). And there is another tool in jenkins that allows you to "block build if certain jobs are running". Also there is an option as "PrerequisitiesCheck".

Let say there is project A triggering project B and B is triggering project C. For the simplicity, let me say this configuration as A->B->C. Let say there is another path like A->X->C. First problem, if A and B are built successfully, C is triggered even Y is being built at the same moment. Solution is to use "block build if certain jobs are running" option. Second problem is, when A triggers B and X, and if B fails, then nevertheless X is triggering C and C fails because of B failed already. That is something that we do not want. Solution (not exact solution) is to use "PrerequisitiesCheck" option. At least with that option the person responsible for the project C can understand the problem did not occur due to project C. Also, we have to use trigger option to be able to link these A->B->C and A->X->C projects each other.

*Problem*

Problem is so simple, We do not want to use these three options (Trigger, PrerequisitiesCheck, Block build if certain jobs are running) because it is too much work and most probably this complex structure will cause many problems (i.e. forgetting linking is the simples one). Is there any tool that is doing three of them at the same time? Do you know any plugin enabling us to solve that problem wity only one linking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multijob plugin will be of interest to you.
This is what the documentation says.

After installing this plugin you will be able to do the following:

```
 When creating new Jenkins job you have an option to create MultiJob project.

 This job can define in the Build section phases that contains one job or more.

 All jobs belong to one phase will be executed in parallel (if there are enough executors on the node)

 All jobs in phase 2 will be executed only after jobs in phase 1 are completed etc.
```

Since A is triggering both B and X, I will make them run in parallel(making them part of same phase) and trigger C only when both are done.

Comment: It seems what I need, but one question:

Comment: I also want to be able to use SCM plugin together with multijob. I mean, lets say I have 5 phases, and the project B (in phase 2) has been changed. So SCM detects the change as you know, then triggers B. After that, will the phase 3 be triggered automatically? It should be but when I try it did not? Maybe multijob plugin is just for triggering the job so called PhaseManager and that job deals with everything? Then thats not what I want. (sorry if it is so complicated to understand, please do not hesitate to ask questions if anything is not clear)

Comment: I think with several manipulations that plug in works good. If any other people needs to configure like me, I could tell the manipulations also. By the way, thanks for answer NotAgain.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the Build Flow Plugin is what you are looking for:
[Build Flow Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin)

There you can write a little script which triggers your existing jobs, for example:

```
parallel (
// job 1, 2 and 3 will be scheduled in parallel.
  { build("job1") },
  { build("job2") },
  { build("job3") }
)
// job4 will be triggered after jobs 1, 2 and 3 complete
build("job4")
```